# Neo4j node property miss

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

An error occurred when save node or relationship node, then node or relationship node's properties lost.

spring data neo4j

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.CRUDRepository.save(U entity)
[ERROR]_2013-12-03 00:11:43:411 :org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: The property 'mobileNumber' does not exist on Node[74629] at
BadInputException
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.exceptionOnNext(RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.java:39)
   org.neo4j.helpers.collection.ExceptionHandlingIterable$1.next(ExceptionHandlingIterable.java:69)
   org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:58)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:57)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:41)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat$1.write(OutputFormat.java:145)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)

org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: The property 'mobileNumber' does not exist on Node[74629] at
BadInputException
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.exceptionOnNext(RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.java:39)
   org.neo4j.helpers.collection.ExceptionHandlingIterable$1.next(ExceptionHandlingIterable.java:69)
   org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:58)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:57)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:41)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat$1.write(OutputFormat.java:145)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)

    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:496)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.query(RestAPIFacade.java:233)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine.query(RestCypherQueryEngine.java:50)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestCypherQueryEngine.query(SpringRestCypherQueryEngine.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestCypherQueryEngine.query(SpringRestCypherQueryEngine.java:27)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.dispatchQuery(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.searchUserInfoes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.searchUserInfoes(Unknown Source)
    at cn.gaialine.talkage2.service.user.impl.UserInfoServiceimpl.searchUserInfoes(UserInfoServiceimpl.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.searchUserInfoes(Unknown Source)
    at cn.gaialine.talkage2.controller.FirendController.searchUserInfoes(FirendController.java:380)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: [ERROR]_2013-12-03 00:15:09:674 :org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: '__type__'

Comment: Neo4j version 1.9.2 stable
Spring-data-neo4j 2.2.0
The cluster is make up of three Neo4j server and a HAProxy.

Comment: Hi, jexp
在使用Neo4j时，遇到几个问题。
我搭建了一个Neo4j集群，有3台Neo4j服务器和1台HAProxy代理服务器组成，目前节点的数量在10万级；
1、Neo4j服务器经常出现宕机，或是出现只能读不能写；
2、数据不完整，保存的数据节点属性好属性值不完整。
目前项目已经上线，希望Neo4j开发团队支持。